# Can I get a Mexican SIM card in Cancun Airport?

Tags: cellphones, mexico, phone-networks

I want to be able to FaceTime the U.K. from Mexico so I’d like to buy a SIM card and put it in my unlocked U.K. iPhone (there’s no WiFi where we’re going).

Will this work and is there somewhere in Cancun airport I can get one when I arrive? Alternatively, is there somewhere near Riviera Maya I can go to get one? (Preferably one that doesn’t cost a fortune for data).

Comment: Can't speak for Cancun specifically, but in Baja there are kiosks and stores all over that sell cellphone accessories and SIM cards.  These are relatively cheap and include data.  I had no problem with these in my NZ bought unlocked Iphone when we moved here.  Please note that cellphone coverage is not great in Mexico unless you're in the cities.

Comment: OXXO stores (rather like 7-11 in the US) are all over, and carry SIM cards.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find online, there is only one place that sells SIM cards at the arrival area of the Cancun airport. It's "just before the exit. It was straightforward." according [to this post.](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g150807-i8-k9976696-o20-Sim_card_for_Mexico_Where_to_buy-Cancun_Yucatan_Peninsula.html)

You can definitely find SIM cards in stores all over Cancun, mostly convenient stores. The best Telcel location would be at [the Centro Maya Mall](http://www.playa-online.com/websites/item/telcel-centro-maya/).

You can also pre-purchase the SIM cards online from Telcel and have them ready before your flight.

It's probably easiest to buy the SIM card at the Centro Mall, where they speak English, though.

Comment: I’ve actually been to Cancun since I asked the question and yes there is a seller just before the exit but I would strongly recommend **not** using them. They are in the middle of all the others trying to flog tourists things and want extortionate amounts. Always been advised not to buy anything from those sellers and you’ll pay quite a premium for no benefit.

Comment: @Notts90 where did you buy yours? You can answer your own question and mark it the answer.

Comment: I didn’t buy one in the end. We weren’t staying near a town and I refused to be ripped off by the traders in the airport.

Answer (score 0):

You can check one Telcel office, is the biggest company in Mexico and you can get a SIM CARD without problems in there, at the airport maybe you can have one, but the price I don't know how much it cost honestly...